# Create class inherirance hierarchy using ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to using ruby to create class inherirance hierarchy. I have grep the class name and its parent class name like this:
[[B,A], [C,A], [E,D], [F,B] ...]

[B,A] A is B's parent class, and the root class not only one, like A or D.
The elements in the array is just string, like A,B,C...

I want to create a inherirance hierarchy graph like this:

```
[
    A=>[
          B=>[F],
          C
        ],
    D=>[E] 
]
```

the graph format is not strict, which can demonstrate the hierarchy will be OK.

I have try to using loop to recursively placed the node, but it's too low efficiency. Does anyone can help me or there is some gem to solve this?

All I want to know is the clas inherirance hierarchy, so whatever the way you solve this.

Thanks @Max and @Gabriel de Oliveira for answer my question! I have solve the problem.
It maybe ugly, but it works.

```
class Node
    attr_accessor :name, :parent, :children
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @parent = nil
        @children = Set.new
    end

    def <=>(other)
        if other.name == self.name
            return 0
        end

        return nil
    end

    def ==(other)
        if other.name == self.name
            return true
        end

        return false
    end

    def inspect
        desc = ""
        desc << "{" if @children.length > 0
        desc << %("#{@name}")
        if @children.count > 0
            desc << ":["
            children_arr = @children.to_a
            children_arr.to_a.each_index do |index|
                desc << ',' if index > 0
                desc << children_arr[index].inspect
            end
            desc << "]"
        end
        desc << "}" if @children.length > 0

        return desc
    end
end


str = string_from_file(file_path)
arr = JSON.parse(str)

nodes = {}

# create nodes set
arr.each do |item|
    name = item[0]
    parent = item[1]

    nodes[name] = Node.new(name)
    nodes[parent] = Node.new(parent)
end

# bind relationship with nodes
arr.each do |item|
    node = nodes[item[0]]
    parent = nodes[item[1]]

    if !parent.nil?
        node.parent = parent
        parent.children << node
    end
end

# filter the root nodes
roots = []
nodes.each_value do |node|
    roots << node if node.parent.nil?
end

puts roots
```

Comment: You could use [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with metaprogramming. `B = Class.new(A)` creates a class `B` that inherits from `A` and `Object.const_set` and `Object.const_get` can dynamically access constants. The only tricky bit is creating the classes in the right order, but that can be solved with recursion.

```
# create class klass (and any necessary superclasses) with inheritance specified by tree
def create_class_from_tree(klass, tree)
  # nothing to do if the class already exists
  return if Object.const_defined? klass

  # default superclass
  parent = Object

  # look for a superclass defined in the tree
  if inherit = tree.find { |k, p| k == klass }
    # ensure superclass exists
    parent = create_class_from_tree(inherit[1], tree)
  end

  Object.const_set(klass, Class.new(parent))
end

# create all classes with inheritance specified by tree
def create_classes_from_tree(tree)
  tree.each { |klass, _| create_class_from_tree(klass, tree) }
end

create_classes_from_tree([['B', 'A'], ['C', 'A'], ['E', 'D'], ['F', 'B']])

('A'..'F').each { |klass| puts "#{klass} < #{Object.const_get(klass).superclass}" }
# A < Object
# B < A
# C < A
# D < Object
# E < D
# F < B
```

Answer (score 0):

To transform the input array into a nested hash you could implement something along these lines:

```
def process(input)
  return {} if input.empty?

  base_classes, rest = input.partition {|value| value.is_a? Class }

  ret_val = {}

  base_classes.each do |klass|
    ret_val[klass], rest = rest.partition {|value| value.last == klass }
    ret_val[klass] = ret_val[klass].map(&:first)
  end 

  ret_val.each {|klass, classes| ret_val[klass] = process(classes + rest) }
end
```

Then given all clases are defined and your `data` array is sanitized (for example it doesn't contain an invalid element such as `[X, Z]`):

```
data = [A, [B, A], [C, A], D, [E, D], [F, B]]
process(data)  #=> {A=>{B=>{F=>{}}, C=>{}}, D=>{E=>{}}}
```